# How to import external C libraries in VSCODE

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compilation, static-libraries

I come here, as I am at a complete loss.
I, for the love of God, cannot manage to include a MySql library properly.
I'm using VSCode, set up c_cpp_properties.json includePath to include mysql, as well as tasks.json.

What am I doing wrong? Why when compiling using either vscode's default gcc or ming64 I still get the fatal error "No such file or directory."

Any help would be very, very appreciated. I just have no clue how to add external libraries and cannot seem to find a good guide explaining it and doing it the "correct" way.

[c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.imgur.com/TmfTrKK.png), [tasks.json](https://i.imgur.com/XMjQ9oo.png), [main.c](https://i.imgur.com/O4bWJfR.png)

I want to properly include an external library in vscode, mysql in this case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not show pictures of text. Instead add your text (config files, C source code, error messages) as formatted text into your question.

Comment: The include path in `c_cpp_properties.json` is just for your editor. The compiler settings are done in `task.json`. You need a line with `"-I ..."` for compiler argument telling the path to the header. BTW: Including a header is very different from including a library. You need to tell your compiler to link with the library as well.

Comment: "I'm using VSCode" That's your problem right here. VSCode is a very unfriendly environment. Use something else.

Answer (score 0):

First off, as already mentioned: VSCode is not a beginner-friendly C++ environment, Visual Studio Community is beginner-friendlier, free and very easy to set up [DOWNLOAD](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

The error is implying that you did not include the mysql_connection.h file into your project, as the output say.

Some tips:
1: Include the actual include directory and not the underlying jdbc directory

2: Include specific headers from underlying folders by using: #include <jdbc/mysql_connection.h>

3: CONFIRM THE LOCATION OF mysql_connection.h, is it even in the jdbc directory?

4: Read the Mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/latest/usage.html

Comment: "Visual Studio Community is beginner-friendlier, free and very easy to set up" ... unless you want a C compiler that's worth its name.